Intelephense error when using VS Code for Joomla development
I'm using VS Code to write some php code within a Joomla installation. Most of the time it works very well, but Intelephense gives a pesky error when I use the JURI::root() function.
I get the error, "Undefined type 'JURI'". I have tried a couple of solutions, including putting the following into my json settings file for the workspace:
"intelephense.environment.includePaths": [
                "../../user/web/imago-home.co.za/public_html/j5d"
        ]

The other solution I see is to create a stubs file, but I haven't been able to get that to work either.
I'm hoping that, by now, this is a solved problem and that I just haven't discovered the solution.
My Joomla installation is on a Linux Ubuntu server that I have full control over (not shared hosting or even VPS).
Thanks in advance!

How are you and VS Code connecting to the remote server? Does it detect other Joomla classes? Do you have any local Joomla installations? VS Code might be picking up the symbols from there.

I'm connecting using the Remote SSH extension. I'm not getting an error on the other Joomla classes, so I presume that those are being detected.  I do have local Joomla installations under WAMP, but I'm not sure if VS Code/Intelephense are picking anything up from there. But your answer below does solve the problem, so I don't think it's necessary to go chasing after too many other details.

As far as I know, VS Code can't include remote paths out of the box. Extensions may be available but chances are they would be very slow. Regarding this specific error, JURI class, in fact, does not exist. It has been renamed to Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri and the JURI alias deprecated. This applies to all J-prefixed global namespace classes. You should consider using the new class names.
Joomla's repository does include a stub generator script but it's been broken since 5.0. This should be reported on the issue tracker. In the meantime, here's the generated stubs.php file https://pastebin.com/J37AJX25 (contents are too large to post in the answer). Here you can see the deprecation:
/**
 * @deprecated 6.0 Use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri instead.
 */
class JUri extends \Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri {}


Thank you, @Sharky, that stubs file solves the problem and also enables Intelephense to show me that JURI has been deprecated. Thanks also for pointing out the need to update to `Joomla\CMS\URI\URI. That will be my next task.
